# Не работает Font Awesome если указывать через :before

Tags: css, шрифты, fontawesome

Столкнулся с проблемой - используя иконки в CSS с помощью псевдоэлементов - вместо самой иконки появляется просто квадрат. Если же указать в HTML через тег `<i>`, то всё работает.
Я пробовал подключать ссылки разных версий, на данный момент стоит последняя:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-VY3F8aCQDLImi4L+tPX4XjtiJwXDwwyXNbkH7SHts0Jlo85t1R15MlXVBKLNx+dj" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Вот пример как я подключал:

```
.breadcrumbs ul li a {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 6px;
    color: #454647;
    padding-right: 35px;
}

.breadcrumbs ul li a:before {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "\f30b";
}
```

Comment: что консоль говорит?

Comment: в консоли всё чисто

Comment: убедитесь что файлы шрифтов подключены

Comment: шрифты подключены через google fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.icon:before {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "\f30b";
    font-weight: 900;
}

.icon2:before {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Brands;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    content: "\f17e";
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<i class="icon"></i>
<br>
<i class="icon2"></i>
```

Смотрите на первый класс иконки
если fab значит:

```
font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Brands;
```

если fas значит:

```
font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
font-weight:900;
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Comment: @nirolo1 без кавычек попробуй

Comment: попробовал, результат тот же

Comment: @nirolo1 у вас ваш css позже загружается чем all.css?

Comment: мой css загружается последним

Answer (score 2):

Почему при выборе **ALL** стрелки отказываются рисоваться не знаю. В режиме **SOLID** они отображаются:

```css
.breadcrumbs ul li a {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 6px;
    color: #454647;
    padding-right: 35px;
}

.breadcrumbs ul li a:before {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "\f30b";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-29Ax2Ao1SMo9Pz5CxU1KMYy+aRLHmOu6hJKgWiViCYpz3f9egAJNwjnKGgr+BXDN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-Lyz+8VfV0lv38W729WFAmn77iH5OSroyONnUva4+gYaQTic3iI2fnUKtDSpbVf0J" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome чувствителен к значению font-weight
У меня бывало пару раз так, что наследовалось значение 400, и я долго не мог понять , что не так! (нужно было прописать значение font-weight 600-900 или bold)